# Not updating in my database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
public void DependentUpdateManScheme(int DependentupdID, string EmployeeID, string Name, string Surname, string IDCardNo, string ContactNo, DateTime BirthDate, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, string Relation, double Payment)
        {
            HealthCareSystem.DataClassesDataContext db = new HealthCareSystem.DataClassesDataContext();

        var z = (from d in db.Dependents
                 where d.EmployeeID.Equals(EmployeeID)
                 join r in db.Relations on d.RelationID equals r.RelationID
                 select new DependentsX { DependentID = d.DependentID, EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID, Name = d.Name, Surname = d.Surname, IDCardNo = d.IDCardNo, ContactNo = d.ContactNo, BirthDate = d.BirthDate, StartSchemeDate = d.StartDate, EndSchemeDate = d.EndDate, RelationType = r.Type, Payment = d.Payment });

        List<DependentsX> oldList = z.ToList();
          foreach (DependentsX dep in oldList)
        {
            dep.DependentID = DependentupdID;
            dep.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
            dep.Name = Name;
            dep.Surname = Surname;
            dep.IDCardNo = IDCardNo;
            dep.ContactNo = ContactNo;
            dep.BirthDate = BirthDate;
            dep.StartSchemeDate = StartDate;
            dep.EndSchemeDate = EndDate;
            dep.RelationID = Convert.ToInt32(Relation);
            dep.Payment = Payment;

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show us your connection string? Does this code run in a web application (or web site) ?

Comment: it is running in a web application. the strange thing is that when i was making an insert it worked perfectly. but when i changed it into an update it didn't update in database. :S

Comment: I was going to change the foreach loop  

      foreach (Dependent d in z)
            {
                d.DependentID = DependentupdID;
                d.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
                 db.SubmitChanges();
            }
and change the query select new instead of a list. but then it is giving me Cannot convert type AnonymousType#1

Answer (score 0):

`DependentsX` is the type of the object that you are updating. This was created in the LINQ Select expression as a new object that is not attached to the context. The context has seen nothing for it to update, so it cannot update anything.

You need to update something that Entity Framework knows about.

Comment: you are saying that i need to create a:

HealthCareSystem.DependentsX upd = new DependentsX();